# Having multiple mat chips inputs on the same form if I complete the first one the rest are also populated

Tags: angular, input

I need a custom component for emails and it contains SendTo list, CC list, and BCC list;
I need it to be a generic one because I am going to reuse it on multiple section on the app;

But, I have that situation: even if there is a different id for any of the mat-chip... functions and all things are related only to the one mat chip element, when I try to add something on the first input, there is automatically completed the rest of inputs with the same chip.
Here is a similar example (the main code is on a separate machine and there are security thing on access stack overflow but there is the exactly same thing)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gjwo4-rfudwx?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts

What I am doing wrong? Is there maybe a small thing that I've missed?

Thank you !

Comment: do you want to have different colors for every chip, can you explain a bit more

Comment: Yes. Actually there are emails, but here is the basi example with colors.

Comment: For the first one a list, for the second one another list.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning both inputs to the same form control while adding , and in the html , you are printing the same form control two times, to make it write , you need to create a different instance for every form control.

you can replace the following code with yours

> chips.input.component.ts

```
  get fruitControls(): FormArray {
    return this.form.controls.fruits as FormArray;
  }
   //add this
  get fruitControls2(): FormArray {
    return this.form.controls.fruits1 as FormArray;
  }
```

and while adding1 assign it to the write form control like this:

```
add1(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruitControls2.push(this.fb.control(value)); //this line is updated
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
```

> chips-input-example.html

```
//the second chip bind it to the wrtie form control
      <mat-chip
        *ngFor="let fruit of fruitControls2.value"
        [selectable]="selectable"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove1(fruit)"
      >
        {{fruit}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
```

i have updated your stackbliz as well

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gjwo4-gbgmzy?

Comment: Thank you!!!  I'll do a try on the main project and come here with a new feedback.

Comment: @Georgiana no wrorries